# Can work happen even if two objects are not in contact. If yes what about this case?

Tags: classical-mechanics

[image]

I do think here work by winning team on the losing team is 0 as they are not in contact?Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Contact forces are short range forces. They do not act at a distance.

The rate of work done by a contact force is $P=\vec F \cdot \vec v$ where $\vec v$ is the velocity of the material at the point of application of $\vec F$. So, assuming that the rope is moving, then it is possible that the winning team could do work on the rope and then the rope could do work on the losing team. If instead the rope is stationary then neither team is doing work on the rope.

Answer (score 0):

They are connected by the rope. If the force **T** is constant and the winning team are stationary and pulls the rope such that the red dot has traveled a distance **s** then they have done **W** = **Ts** amount of work.

Two objects do not necessarily have to be in contact (think about a point charge being repelled by a stationary charge of the same sign due to its electric field). The condition is that whoever or whatever is doing the work has to exert a some force over some distance.